# search for formatted date inside a string and replace it with current date php

Tags: php, string

I need to search inside the string and replace it with the current `date`

This what i have tried yet.
It works fine, it replaces the date into the current date, but the problem is, that I need the initial date to be dynamic, so i can use any date.

```
<?php 
    $string = 'we will be held the event in 12/2017 . and waiting for your ..';
    $anydigit = '12/2017';
    $str = str_replace($anydigit,  date(), $string);
    var_dump ($str);

?>
```

```
 <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="panel panel-default>
                <div class="panel-body">
                     <p> we will be held the event in 12/2017 . and waiting for your </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>  
    </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: We are always glad to help and support new coders but ***you need to help yourself first. :-)*** After [**doing more research**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/1011527) if you have a problem **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a good question. Be sure to [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/1011527).

Comment: @AbraCadaver btw your regex doesn't take the `/` into account

Comment: @Davіd: Could have sworn I typed it :-)

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you want a regex: [`/\d{2}\/\d{4}/`](https://regex101.com/r/dEyaOM/2)

You also need to pass a format to [`date`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php).

Full code:

```
$string   = 'we will be held the event in 12/2017 . and waiting for your ..';
$str      = preg_replace('/\d{2}\/\d{4}/', date('Y/m/d'), $string);
var_dump($str);
```

[eval.in demo](https://eval.in/931144)

Comment: Case `i`nsensitive digits?

Comment: Good point @AbraCadaver Just a habit of mine I guess. Editing now.